# The pandas value error still shows, but the code is totally correct and it loads normally the visualization

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I really wanted to use `pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None`, but I wanted a code clean of error.

My start code:

```py
import datetime
import altair as alt
import operator
import pandas as pd
s = pd.read_csv('../../data/aparecida-small-sample.csv', parse_dates=['date'])

city = s[s['city'] == 'Aparecida']
```

Based on [@dpkandy](/users/15592592/dpkandy)'s code:

```
city['total_cases'] = city['totalCases']
city['total_deaths'] = city['totalDeaths']
city['total_recovered'] = city['totalRecovered']

tempTotalCases = city[['date','total_cases']]
tempTotalCases["title"] = "Confirmed"

tempTotalDeaths = city[['date','total_deaths']]
tempTotalDeaths["title"] = "Deaths"

tempTotalRecovered = city[['date','total_recovered']]
tempTotalRecovered["title"] = "Recovered"

temp = tempTotalCases.append(tempTotalDeaths)
temp = temp.append(tempTotalRecovered)

totalCases = alt.Chart(temp).mark_bar().encode(alt.X('date:T', title = None), alt.Y('total_cases:Q', title = None))
totalDeaths = alt.Chart(temp).mark_bar().encode(alt.X('date:T', title = None), alt.Y('total_deaths:Q', title = None))
totalRecovered = alt.Chart(temp).mark_bar().encode(alt.X('date:T', title = None), alt.Y('total_recovered:Q', title = None))

(totalCases + totalRecovered + totalDeaths).encode(color=alt.Color('title', scale = alt.Scale(range = ['#106466','#DC143C','#87C232']), legend = alt.Legend(title="Legend colour"))).properties(title = "Cumulative number of confirmed cases, deaths and recovered", width = 800)
```

This code works perfectly and loaded normally the visualization image, but it still shows the pandas error, asking to try to set `.loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead`, then I was reading the documentation "Returning a view versus a copy" whose linked cited and also tried this code, but it still shows the same error. Here is the code with `loc`:

```py
# 1st attempt
tempTotalCases.loc["title"] = "Confirmed"
tempTotalDeaths.loc["title"] = "Deaths"
tempTotalRecovered.loc["title"] = "Recovered"

# 2nd attempt
tempTotalCases["title"].loc = "Confirmed"
tempTotalDeaths["title"].loc = "Deaths"
tempTotalRecovered["title"].loc = "Recovered"
```

Here is the error message:

```
<ipython-input-6-f16b79f95b84>:6: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  tempTotalCases["title"] = "Confirmed"
<ipython-input-6-f16b79f95b84>:9: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  tempTotalDeaths["title"] = "Deaths"
<ipython-input-6-f16b79f95b84>:12: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  tempTotalRecovered["title"] = "Recovered"
```

Jupyter and Pandas version:

```
$ jupyter --version
jupyter core     : 4.7.1
jupyter-notebook : 6.3.0
qtconsole        : 5.0.3
ipython          : 7.22.0
ipykernel        : 5.5.3
jupyter client   : 6.1.12
jupyter lab      : 3.1.0a3
nbconvert        : 6.0.7
ipywidgets       : 7.6.3
nbformat         : 5.1.3
traitlets        : 5.0.5

$ pip show pandas
Name: pandas
Version: 1.2.4
Summary: Powerful data structures for data analysis, time series, and statistics
Home-page: https://pandas.pydata.org
Author: None
Author-email: None
License: BSD
Location: /home/gus/PUC/.env/lib/python3.9/site-packages
Requires: pytz, python-dateutil, numpy
Required-by: ipychart, altair
```

### Update 2

I followed the answer, it worked, but there is another problem:

```
temp = tempTotalCases.append(tempTotalDeaths)
temp = temp.append(tempTotalRecovered)
```

Error log:

```
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  iloc._setitem_with_indexer(indexer, value, self.name)
InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidIndexError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-b2649a676837> in <module>
     17 tempTotalRecovered.loc["title"] = _("Recovered")
     18 
---> 19 temp = tempTotalCases.append(tempTotalDeaths)
     20 temp = temp.append(tempTotalRecovered)
     21 
~/GitLab/Gustavo/global/.env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in append(self, other, ignore_index, verify_integrity, sort)
   7980             to_concat = [self, other]
   7981         return (
-> 7982             concat(
   7983                 to_concat,
   7984                 ignore_index=ignore_index,
~/GitLab/Gustavo/global/.env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/concat.py in concat(objs, axis, join, ignore_index, keys, levels, names, verify_integrity, sort, copy)
    296     )
    297 
--> 298     return op.get_result()
    299 
    300 
~/GitLab/Gustavo/global/.env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/concat.py in get_result(self)
    514                     obj_labels = obj.axes[1 - ax]
    515                     if not new_labels.equals(obj_labels):
--> 516                         indexers[ax] = obj_labels.get_indexer(new_labels)
    517 
    518                 mgrs_indexers.append((obj._mgr, indexers))
~/GitLab/Gustavo/global/.env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_indexer(self, target, method, limit, tolerance)
   3169 
   3170         if not self.is_unique:
-> 3171             raise InvalidIndexError(
   3172                 "Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects"
   3173             )
InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects
```

Comment: These are warnings, not errors, which is why it says `SettingWithCopyWarning` and why it appears to do something successfully. You should still try to write the code in a way that avoids the warning. To start, try taking the advice explicitly given to you in the warning.

Comment: "then I was reading the documentation "Returning a view versus a copy" whose linked cited and also tried this code" Tried *what* code? The warning says to `Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead`. I don't see any code in your post that mentions `.loc` at all. We can only help you with code we can actually see.

Comment: Done, @KarlKnechtel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `SettingWithCopyWarning` is a `warning` and not an `error`. The importance in this distinction is that `pandas` isn't sure whether your code will produce the intended output so is letting the programmer make this decision where as a `error` means that something is definitely wrong.

The `SettingWithCopyWarning` is warning you about the difference between when you do something like `df['First selection']['Second selection']` compared to `df.loc[:, ('First selection', 'Second selection')`.

In the first case 2 separate events occur `df['First selection']` takes place, then the object returned from this is used for the next seleciton `returned_df['Second selection']`. `pandas` has no way to know whether the `returned_df` is the original `df` or just temporary 'view' of this object. Most of the time is doesn't matter (see docs for more info)...but if you want to change a value on a temporary view of an object you'll be confused as to why your code runs error free but you don't see changes you made reflected. Using `.loc` bundles `'First selection'` and `'Second selection'` into one call so `pandas` can guarantee that what's returned is not just a view.

The [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#why-does-assignment-fail-when-using-chained-indexing) you linked show's you why your attempts to use `.loc` didn't work at you intended (eg. taken from docs):

> ```
> def do_something(df):
>     foo = df[['bar', 'baz']]  # Is foo a view? A copy? Nobody knows!
>     # ... many lines here ...
>     # We don't know whether this will modify df or not!
>     foo['quux'] = value
>     return foo
> ```

You have something similar in your code. Look at  how `tempTotalCases` is created:

```
city = s[s['city'] == 'Aparecida']
# some lines of code    
tempTotalCases = city[['date','total_cases']]
```

And then some more lines of code before you attempt to do:

```
tempTotalCases.loc["title"] = "Confirmed"
```

So `pandas` throws the warning.

Separate from your original question you might find `df.rename()` useful. [Link to docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html).

You'll be able to do something like:

```
city = city.rename(columns={'totalCases': 'total_cases',
                            'totalDeaths': 'total_deaths',
                            'totalRecovered': 'total_recovered})
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, I understood your answer and applied the logic, it almost worked, but another error appeared. It is about `temp = tempTotalCases.append(tempTotalDeaths)`. Please check my second update. Thank you.

Comment: Glad you're making progress. It's difficult to help with your new error without knowing what `tempTotalCases` or `tempTotalDeaths` are. The error is telling that `tempTotalCases.index` doesn't consist of unique values, so any operation which aligns or orders by index will fail. Before attempting `.append()` you can use `.reset_index()` (NB by default this is not in place) on your objects. Or pass the keyword argument `.append(ignore_index=True) . You'll need to look at your data to make decide which is most appropriate.